# firefox can't follow the link, in other browsers all right

Tags: hyperlink, nofollow

Ggo to https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVGXZG hover mouse on NAV and try click on "firefox"
Other browser when you click on "firefox" following link without problem

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("main-btn");

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
  var nav = document.getElementById("main-nav");
  var sub_btns = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-btn");
  var pos = [];
  e.className += "main-hover";
  console.log(e)
  nav.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
      var total =0;
      for(var x = 0;x<sub_btns.length;x++) {
        if(x <2) {
          sub_btns[x].style.left = "-"+((x+1)*30)+"%";
          pos[x] = ((x+1)*20);
        } else {
           sub_btns[x].style.right = "-"+((x-1)*30)+"%";
           pos[x] = ((x-1)*280);
        }
        sub_btns[x].style.opacity = "1";
      }
      nav.style.width = 50+"%";

  });
  
  nav.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    nav.style.width = "100px";

    for(var x = 0;x<sub_btns.length;x++) {
      sub_btns[x].style.left = "0";
      sub_btns[x].style.right = "0";
      sub_btns[x].style.opacity = "0";
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Spec says, that inside of  you can have only phrasing content. That is, the  element inside  won't be interactive (clickable).